# Nixos container with custom user systemd unit

Tags: nix, nixos

I've defined the following container:

```
  containers.abc123 = {
    config = { config, pkgs, ... }:
    {
      systemd.user.services = {
        finder = {
          description = "finder";
          enable = true;
          serviceConfig = {
            Type      = "simple";
            ExecStart = "${pkgs.coreutils}/bin/mkdir /tmp/hello";
            Restart   = "always";
            RestartSec   = 50;
          };
          wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
        };
      };
    };
  };
```

Essentially a test `finder` service defined. However, this does not seem to work according to the output from:

```
sudo nixos-container run abc123 -- systemctl status finder
Unit finder.service could not be found.
sudo nixos-container run abc123 -- systemctl status --user finder
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I thought perhaps these 'user' services don't run for the root user. But after adding a user and logging in, still no change.

```
sudo nixos-container root-login abc123

[root@abc123:~]# systemctl status --user finder
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

[root@abc123:~]# su test123

[test123@abc123:/root]$ systemctl status --user finder
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

[test123@abc123:/root]$ systemctl status finder
Unit finder.service could not be found.
```

---

Why isn't this service working? Is it not supported in nixos containers?

Comment: Chris, Hensing's comment was moved to an answer - you said it worked for you, please consider accepting his answer if you still think it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nixos-container root-login` does the bare minimum to give you a shell; [`nsenter` and `su`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/4f165c6d7d4dcd216c95dc02a875d2ab09f65821/pkgs/tools/virtualization/nixos-container/nixos-container.pl#L449)

The command `nixos-container login` should work. That's backed by `machinectl login`, which can set things up properly so `systemctl` can do its job.